# MySQL Entity Framework 6: Database First. How to create classes?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-database-first

Until now I've been using EF6 with Visual Studio, mostly code first, rarely database first.

To import some test data, someone gave me the connection to a database in MySQL. In MySql Workbench I can query data, so the connection works.

Now I want to create an Entity Framework Database First project and import the database model. In Visual Studio

- Create Project,
- Add nuget: Entity Framework newest version (6.1.3)
- Add nuget: MySql.Data.entities for EF 6
- Add new item

And now? There is an EF 6.X `DbContext` generator, but that one does not work until I've got the model

I can do what I normally do:

- select ADO.NET entity data model
- EF Designer from database
- And now? How to connect to MySql?

**Addition**

Mehmet referred me to [MySql EF6 Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) (thanks Mehmet), a page that came first when I googled. Maybe this is the correct way, but I don't understand whtat it says The first steps: add the connection string and add the reference (= install nuget package?) I can manage, but after that it's all Greek to me:

- Set the new DbConfiguration class for MySql. *THE new `DbConfiguration` class*? Which `DbConfiguration` class? Where, and how to set it for MySQL?
- Add the `DbConfigurationTypeAttribute` to the `DbContext`. Alas, I haven't got a `DbContext` yet, it's not code first, but database first: some wizard is supposed to determine the `DbSets` in the `DbContext` for me.

So maybe this is the way to go, but this is too cryptical for me.

Comment: You can find your need at below link
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: No, I finally used Dapper to read all the data from the old data base and used entity framework code-first to insert the read data in the new database

Comment: I believe what you want to do is scaffold. I had the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to install some NuGet on your NuGet administrator

   ```
   microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
   microsoftEntityFrameworkCore.Tools
   Microsoft.NETCore.App
   Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL
   ```
2. After having all your NuGet, you need to apply this to your Package Console Administrator:

   ```
   Scaffold-DbContext 
   "Server=localhost;Database=database_name;User=root;Password=123456;" 
   "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" -Outputdir Models
   ```

This will create a context for all your models and will also create some models for your data base.